# filtering Dynamo DB in Step functions JSONPath

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I am trying to build a step function that has a choice state based on a map in a result of a dynamo db map. An example result from my dynamo GetItem request would be.

```
{
"Item": {
  "organisationId": {
    "S": "Andys-test"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "Andy2"
  },
  "states": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "year": {
            "N": "2021"
          },
          "status": {
            "S": "started"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "year": {
            "N": "2022"
          },
          "status": {
            "S": "started"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
},
```

My condition will be checking the status of the states map against the year 2021. I have attempted to use this JSONPath which from what I can tell is valid, although I am getting nothing in the data flow simulator in the step functions console. I have tried various iterations of the below, with quotes escaped quotes etc and can't get anything to parse the correct value out.
I have been doing this in the input selector as I can see that the result path does not support the [?()] notation.

```
$.Item.states.L..M[?(@.year.N ==  2022) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example choice state with some rules, it'll be hard to answer definitively but I think I'm following.

#### JSONPath with expression filters

I run into this sort of problem more often than I'd like when using JSONPath filter expressions and have to add "helper" tasks to get things moving (*wasting valuable state transitions*  ).

When you specify a [**Path**](https://states-language.net/spec.html#path) that includes a [*filter expression*](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators), the result is always going to be a *list* (and you won't be able to reference index afterwards either).

[image: jsonpath filter expression (Path) vs specifying a specific node (Reference Path)]

[ChoiceRules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules) don't really have a comparator that deals with arrays/lists (at least i haven't been able to get it to work, so let me know if you do ).

The hack I've found easiest to reason about/maintain is creating a simple **Pass Task** that "pops" the values I need from the filter expression and then pass that along to the **Choice Task**.

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72555205/4526019) from one of my previous answers (the pattern used in the  `PassDef` task would be defined *before* your choice task in your scenario, instead of after)

---

I've found it easier to start with  https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com then progress to the data flow simulator. Just remember to always keep in mind whether
you're trying implement a `Path` or a `Reference Path`!